# ECharts: Force XAxis Labels to show all the values for type=time without any duplicate values

Tags: reactjs, echarts

I am facing some issues with Echarts-Line Charts while trying to render the label data on the X-Axis.

**Scenario 1 –  Plotting XAxis Labels when only single quarter information is available**

Expected Output: Only a single label should appear on XAxis.

[Expected Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YNzNJ.png)

Actual Output [Echarts] –  Duplicate xAxis labels

[Echart Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTDGJ.png)

I want to have one to one mapping between data and xAxis label.

**Scenario 2 –  Plotting XAxis labels when there is a huge dataset**

Expected Output :- The labels on xAxis has all the quarter information.

[Expected Output when dataset is large](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Etc2J.png)

Actual Output [Echarts]-  Some XAxis labels are skipped automatically by Echarts library, I have tried rotation but it still skips the datapoints.

[Actual: xAxis Labels got skipped](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EFcUp.png)

I want to force Echart to show all the labels irrespective of the overlapping of values.

Sample Code:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactEcharts from 'echarts-for-react';

const LineChart : React.FC = (props) => {

var option2={
title: {
    text: ''
},          
tooltip: {
    trigger: 'item'
},
legend: {
    x: 'left',
    padding: [0, 0, 0, 40],
    data: ['Plot this']
},
// Impacts the grid lines, LRBT are kind of a padding which moves the chart
grid: {
    show: true,
    left: '3%',
    containLabel: true,
    borderColor: 'white'
},
xAxis: {
    name: "Category",
    nameLocation: "middle",
    nameTextStyle: {
      padding: [10, 0, 0, 0]
    },
    type: 'time',
    boundaryGap: false,
    splitNumber: 0,
    axisLabel: {
      interval:0,
      showMinLabel: true,
      showMaxLabel:true,
      formatter: (function (value:any, index:any) {
          const date = new Date(value * 1);
          const month = (date.getMonth() + 1);
          // to ignore duplicate values
          if (!([1,4,7,10].includes(month))){
            return null;
          }
          const quarter = `Q${Math.ceil(month / 3)}`
          const year = date.getFullYear()
          const xAxisData = `${quarter}-${year}`
          return xAxisData
      })
      // formatter:'Q{Q}-{yyyy}'
  }
    
},
yAxis: {
    name: "",
    nameLocation: "middle",
    nameTextStyle: {
      padding: [0, 0, 30, 0]
    },
    splitArea:{
      show:true,
      areaStyle:{
       color:["white", "#FAFBFC"]
       }
     },
    type: 'value'
},
series: [
    {
        name: 'Plot This',
        type: 'line',
        symbol: 'emptyCircle',
        color: '#00A3E0',
        symbolSize: 10,
        lineStyle: {
          type: 'solid'
        },
        emphasis: {
          focus: 'series',
          blurScope: 'coordinateSystem'
      },
        data: [
        [1506816000000, 509680038.04382974],
        [1514764800000, 791155276.2344121],
        [1522540800000, 799123227.7082155],
        [1530403200000, 802979755.202323],
        [1538352000000, 808190497.8038454],
        [1546300800000, 948760339.9516863],
        [1554076800000, 1042540676.5278728],
        [1561939200000, 875160118.2571102],
        [1569888000000, 712878628.868768],
        [1577836800000, 735685154.726105],
        [1585699200000, 820177866.0564957],
        [1593561600000, 818982140.8503832],
        [1601510400000, 815904376.9750341],
        [1609459200000, 836625579.7082175],
        [1617235200000, 832549982.9206431],
        [1625097600000, 828002503.802811],
        [1633046400000, 821488484.2030047],
        [1640995200000, 823540791.742887],
        [1648771200000, 818621496.9663928],
        [1656633600000, 813346336.6927732],
        [1664582400000, 808353924.8521348],
        [1672531200000, 804944324.4562442],
        [1680307200000, 799921655.5844442]
  ]
    },
  ]
}
return (

<div>
  <p> </p>
  <ReactEcharts
  option = {option2}
  />
</div>
);
}

export default LineChart;
```

Output of the above code:
[XAxis with Missing Quarters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lF4Db.png)

Replace the data of the series with below to get the Scenario 1:

```
    data: [
    [1506816000000, 509680038.04382974],
     ]
```

Output:
[Duplicate Quarters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YHx1n.png)

Thanks in advance.